# Magento backend showing blank pages after login?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I have magento 1.9 version and It is working fine on local and demo server but when I move this to live server its admin is not working.It just login admin and only header and navigation bar shows up there.
I tried with remove cache, sessions.disabled all newly installed extensions.but still same problem.My frontend is working fine.
Please help me to solve this issues.

Comment: did you check what's in system and exception logs? Maybe you can try on remove comment of line: `#ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in `index.php` in order to see the error

Comment: Yes I did that but no error on back-end. Unfortunately, No system log no exception log there.

Answer (score 0):

This error was coming due to some entries in table "**adminnotification_inbox**" . I don't know why this happened.I just empty this table and my admin works fine but as soon as this table have entry same problem occurs, So After empty that table I disable admin notification from following location:-

```
System->Advanced->Disable Modules Output

Mage_AdminNotification
```

This solved my problem.

Comment: so strange solutions. Have you check the entry which creating the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

flush your magento root `/var/cache` folder and `/var/session` folders, It may have previous server session that may cause problems.